# Whether a blank string should be localized in ios

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I have a label which will show the text which I have added using the below code

```
m_label = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",retValue]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:NSLocalizedString(@"DAYS",nil)];
```

So here the text will be displayed in this format: 10(space)days.
I have localised the "days" string,I want to know whether we should localise a space or blank string,

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: why would you localise it? just in case in a specific language the space is not used as a separator?

Comment: Ya I thought because of that only..but dont know whether I am right

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the languages you are targeting, in the end.

I don't see any particular risks with the expression "10 days", in almost any language I know the number of days would be separated from the word "days" by a space. Of course, I don't know all the languages in the world.

Just an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
m_label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", 
           retValue, NSLocalizedString(@"DAYS",nil)];
```

If the need arises, you can localize the format string. That way, you will not only get flexibility on whitespace, but also e.g., on ordering: putting "DAYS" before their count.